# Aggregate $unwind in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hi I'm trying to do a query using aggregation(mongodb version 2.2) to return a list of products in a certain store owned by a certain user. I think I have the first 2 steps correctly, but stuck on the next ones.

Data:

[image: Mongo document]

Here's the incomplete query I have:

```
  collection.aggregate( 
  [ { '$match': { "username": test } },
    { '$unwind': '$stores'} 
  ],      
  function(err, results) {
    assert.equal(err, null);

    console.log(results)
    callback(results);
  }
```

);

Can anyone advice on how to go about with the next few ones?

Comment: You can try something like this. `{ '$match': { 'stores.name': "storename"} }, { '$project': { 'products': "$stores.products"} }`

Comment: @Veeram that worked perfectly. thanks!